# Is there any elegant way in LINQ to bucket a collection into a set of lists based on a property

Tags: c#, linq, collections

i have a collection of cars.  I want to bucket this into separate lists by a property of the car . . .lets say brand.

So if i have a collection of some Ford, some Chevy, some BMW, etc, i want a seperate list for each of those buckets.

something like:

```
IEnumberable<Car> myCarCollection = GetCollection();

List<IEnumerable<Car>> buckets = myCarCollection.BucketBy(r=>r.Brand)
```

does something exist like this or do i need to do this "manually" through loops

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
return myCarCollection.GroupBy(r => r.Brand);
```